# Read string items split by lines as list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Given multiple string lines copied from text file as follows:

```
sh
bj
cd
gz
hz
```

How could I convert and read them as a list:

```
 ['sh', 'bj', 'cd', 'gz', 'hz']
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are directly reading these lines from a text file, try this:

```py
f = open("filename.txt","r")

word_lst = f.readlines()

word_lst = [word.strip() for word in word_lst] # Removes all the following and trailing whitespaces

f.close()
```

If you have these words as a string and you want to convert them into a list, then try this:

```py
string = """sh
bj
cd
gz
hz"""

word_lst = string.split("\n")

print(word_lst)
```

Output:

```
['sh', 'bj', 'cd', 'gz', 'hz']
```